# Gradient of $w \mapsto\|y-Xw\|_2^2$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, quadratic-forms, least-squares

When I try to find the gradient of the MSE loss $$L(w)=\|y-Xw\|_2^2$$ (ignoring constant factors) I find two different solutions, one is the transpose of the other:

1. [Compute the gradient of mean square error](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1962877) claims the gradient is $$\nabla L(w)=X^TXw-X^Ty$$
2. [MSE Loss function and derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784799) claims it is $$\nabla L(w)=w^TX^TX-y^TX$$

I also tried doing it myself:

$$ \begin{aligned} L(w) &= \|y-Xw\|^2 \\ &= (y-Xw)^T(y-Xw) \\ &= (y^T-w^TX^T)(y-Xw) \\ &= (y^Ty-y^TXw-w^TX^Ty+w^TX^TXw) \end{aligned} $$

and

$$\nabla L(w) = -y^TX - y^TX + w^T(X^TX+(X^TX)^T) = 2(w^TX^TX-y^TX)$$

which is equivalent to the second post. Why am I getting the transposed solution?

Comment: They are conceptually the same. The only difference is whether you want to represent a gradient as a column vector (1) or as a row vector (2).

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222894/339790)

Comment: I see, thanks. I wasn't aware that this wasn't standardized.

So if I want to get a column vector I should use d(Ax)/dx = A^T and d(x^TAx)/dx = (A^T + A)x?